# Better way in java to Assert json array key values are sorted in asc or desc order?

Tags: java, json

I have a json response like below

```
"userDetails":[  
    { "userId" : 1,
      "userName" : "abc"
    },
    { "userId" : 2,
      "userName" : "bcd"
    }
]
```

I want to write java code to assert whether "userDetails" array is sorted in ascending/descending order of "userId" key values.

Comment: loop through and check the value with the last value

Comment: "I want to write java code" that's a noble desire. What is stopping you from doing just that? If you code to post (as a [mcve]) and a description of the problem you're having, people could help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONAssert from :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Using the following samples:-

```
String result = "[Alex, Barbera, Charlie, Xavier]";
JSONAssert.assertEquals(
"[Charlie, Alex, Xavier, Barbera]", result, JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);
JSONAssert.assertEquals(
"[Alex, Barbera, Charlie, Xavier]", result, JSONCompareMode.STRICT);
JSONAssert.assertNotEquals(
"[Charlie, Alex, Xavier, Barbera]", result, JSONCompareMode.STRICT);
```

It is very useful in the scenario where the API returns an array of sorted elements, and we want to verify if the response is sorted.

Reference:- http://www.baeldung.com/jsonassert

Comment: Looks nice for unit tests, but I think OP wants to test whether an unknown collection is sorted over a key, and I don't see how they'll do that with an `assertEquals`

Comment: @nandal I want to check sorting based on a particular key in json